# Duplicate formfields that are stored in an table structure

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this function to add an extra `inputfield` if the last `inputfield` in a loop is clicked.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('focus', 'div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){
      var sInputGroupHtml = $('div.input-group-option:last-child').html();

      var sInputGroupClasses = $('div.input-group-option').attr('class');

      $('div.input-group-option').parent().append(`<div class="${sInputGroupClasses}">${sInputGroupHtml}</div>`);

    });
});
```

This works fantastic for this case:

```
<div class="input-group-option-container">';
    for($y = 0; $y <= 4; $y++) { echo '
    <div class="input-group-option">

    <div class="form-group" id="calc_pos_nr_div['.$y.'][]">
        <input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="calc_pos_nr['.$y.'][]" name="calc_pos_nr[]" value="">
        <span class="" id="calc_pos_nr_glyp['.$y.'][]"></span>
    </div>

    </div>'; } echo '
</div>
```

But when this div is in a table structure it is not working, any suggestions how tot change the script to be able to work with tables as well?

```
    <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Pos.nr</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<div class="input-group-option-container">';
        <?php for($y = 0; $y <= 4; $y++) { echo '
        <div class="input-group-option">

          <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group" id="calc_pos_nr_div['.$y.'][]">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="calc_pos_nr['.$y.'][]" name="calc_pos_nr[]" value="">
                    <span class="" id="calc_pos_nr_glyp['.$y.'][]"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </div> } ?>
    </div>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The table-tag is missing. (div between table and tr is an error). Also note that PHP supports Heredoc

Comment: @Teson I did only put down the code that seemed necessary for this problem, I have now added the table to my example.

Comment: "In the html tables, <table> tag expect <tr> tag right after itself and <tr> tag expect <td> tag right after itself. So if you want to put a div in table, you can put it in between <td> and </td> tags as data. You can't put a div directly inside a table but you can put div inside td or th element." (google)

Comment: OK, that is just **ked up @Teson :) Seems a big challenge now, any suggestion how to work with this then?

Comment: Your JS needs an update, probably to: $('.input-group-option-container tr:last-child td').click()